# ApplyFiler and Append Query with Macro in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, filter, append, ms-access-2010

[image: Error]

Is there a way to apply a filter to a query by using a macro? I have attached an image of what I am attempting. Thank you.

[image: Macro]

Comment: Well, did you try it out?

Comment: The OpenQuery actually run the query before the ApplyFilter takes place, so no filtering is done on the AppendQuery

Answer (score 0):

You should have query results displayed as a datasheet subform in the main form. Also in the main form you should have a command button to run your macro. If that's the case, all your macro needs is:

```
ApplyFilter
    Filter Name
    Where Condition = [Region]="US"
    Control Name Datasheetname
```

Alternatively your command button could run an event procedure:

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Click()
    Me.Subformname.Form.Filter = "[Region] = " & US & ""
    Me.Subformname.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Dave, I have inculded an image of the error I am getting while trying this macro. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Your query results should be displayed on the form in some way, for example a datasheet as a subform control. At that point, it's easy to have a command button control to run your macro containing an ApplyFilter action. Alternatively, you could have the command button run a small piece of VBA code to do the same. Your preference.